# Index everything and exclude certain div

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm trying to index everything in document like this:

```
var index = $('body *').index(this);
```

So now I want to remove the text from all items:

```
$('body *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

The problem is that I would like to exclude a certain element from the remove function. This element has a number as text like this:

```
 <li id="2">2</li>
```

So the remove function should not remove the text from `li` with `id="2"`, according to its `index(2)`. How do I do this? This is what I have so far: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p83Rg/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as the selector for the "not" element...

```
var qw = $('li:eq(' + $("span").text() + ')');
```

See this updated fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/p83Rg/7/

I would strongly recommend using an ID to identify the span though, as this will obviously break if there are any other spans on the page :)

Comment: Hi, Im not looking for a workaround...I need to preserve it by its index which is number 2 (zero-based index)

Comment: This isn't a workaround.  I guess I don't understand your question at all then.

Comment: My question was a bit confusing I realize now..Take a look at this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p83Rg/6/ I have put the number two inside a span. Now I would like to preserve the list item by its index. The index holds value 0,1,2 So I need to preserve by the text in span(variable). In this case it is number two. (hope Im clear now..)

Comment: So basically "not the index number given by span.text"

Comment: Okay, I've updated the fiddle and will update the answer to suit that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude it with the selector:

```
$('body *').not("li#2").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

Comment: I would like to exclude it with the text of #2 (which is the indexed number)

Answer (score 0):

Before the `.remove()` insert a `.not('#2')`

Comment: Im looking for a way to exclude by its index which is given by text of #2